# SaxParser doesn't throw exception

Tags: saxparser

i have html file, which is parsed with SaxParser without any exception
i use nonValidating parser. And i couldn't understand why there aren't any exception.
What it can be?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. Maybe the file is valid XML or you're parsing not the file that you expect or some part of the code swallows the exception.

Comment: in what case html file will be valid as xml?

Comment: i've debuged code for many times. and think that the only possibility is that it is well-formed xml. bit i want to prove it

Comment: When an XML parser doesn't throw an exception :-) Please see the rules for valid XML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling